# How to update RecyclerView using Kotlin and Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display data from my Room database on RecyclerView, it works fine except when I fill in new data and try to update my RecyclerView it doesn't update. Here's part of the code that I tried using:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
        val adapter = MainAdapter(myData)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

**MainAdapter.kt**

```
        fun refresh(data: List<NewList>) {
            val currentList: MutableList<MyList> = mutableListOf()
            currentList.clear()
            currentList.addAll(data)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

I am trying to call this function from Fragment file so it can pass updated list from Room Database (It updates list once someone opens that fragment)

**Fragment.kt**

```
        var myData = App.instance.db.getAllDao().getAll()
        val adapter = MainAdapter(myData)
        adapter.refresh(myData)
```

I printed updated list in the `updateData()` function and it does show updated list, as well as tried printing ItemCount and it also shows updated ItemCount, but does not update actual display with new data.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter attached to the RecyclerView in MainActivity and in fragment are not same.

Answer (score 0):

just delete adapter creation in Fragment and pass RecyclerView instance to Fragment and then set layout manager and adapter there instead of activity. lastly call `updateData` method in order to be able to populate adapter.

Comment: I am still very new to this, how would I go about passing adapter instance to Fragment?

Comment: AFAIS you defined recyclerview in Activity but u want to sent new data to adapter in fragment so you should access activity instance in fragment and then you need to access recyclerview through it by using (activity as MainActivity).recyclerView and just set adapter in fragment instead of activity and lastly pass data to adapter there

Comment: btw dont forget to define recyclerview as global variable in order to be able to access it in Fragment